# How a chose between strict vs dynamic measurement of moving average

Tags: statistics, python

I am building a simple stock model with Pandas and part of that is calculating moving averages.

I would like to understand what are and how to measure accuracy implications of using strict vs dynamic time window size when calculating long-term moving averages.

Here is an example what I mean:

I have a csv file with TLSA stock history between 1.1.2000 - 28.2.2017

```
df = pd.read_csv('TSLA.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
# add new col to dataframe consisting of a 100 day moving avarage
df['100ma'] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=100, min_periods=0).mean()
```

min_periods=0 allows me to calculate moving average for the first 100 days where don't have 100 days using first 0, 1, 2, 3... moving average.

My alternative to this is call `df.dropna()` it would drop first 100 rows that don't have a 100-day moving average. Downside I would have exact average but fewer data points.

I am building a tool using a large number of moving averages. What would be a correct method to figure which data frame to use? Correlation to a moving average of a representing stock index? Also which technique is usually applied in the quant world?

Intuitively I think dynamic version is more representing but is that true also with minute and shorter timeframe data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in my code is to calculate the MA for "whatever number of days is available or 100 whichever is smaller". But that is just a pragmatic hack to make sure my program produces some value instead of dying of unexplained causes, and matches the "correct" values once T>= 100. I would not claim that this is the definitive solution by any means. The routine should probably return a Warning Code that the full MA cannot yet be computed, so the caller can disregard those fake values if he wants. Of course before the date of TSLA IPO I return a Hard Error code saying "can't do it". This is programming style rather than Quant Finance.